# Mathjax formula is not showing properly on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, mathjax

I'm using CKEditor as rich text editor. For mathematical formulas I included MathJax plugin. The problem is, when I insert formula in editor's panel - it's working and showing properly, for example, [image: view in editor's panel] but in show page it's rendering only this, for example: `\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)`. What should I do?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Additionally, I added this `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>` code also.

Comment: :))) Now I faced another problem: `<p><span class="math-tex">
`EQUATION`</span></p>`. What is this? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved it myself :))))) I added `raw(somethingToBeShown)`. It worked!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The MathJax plugin for ckeditor only converts a TeX string inside the Editor into a readable equation. The original source will still be the TeX string, and if you only put that content in your page - you will see the TeX string: `\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)` (as in your example).

The easiest way to "solve" this is to add the MathJax script to your page (not the editor), which will translate the TeX parts in your html to the readable equations:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
```

src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">

Here is a working example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>



<div>The next line should be displayed as equation (and not just string) if the MathJax was loaded correctly:</div>
<div style="margin: 20px;">
\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)
</div>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.